# SignalR and Groups.Add in foreach

Tags: c#, asynchronous, signalr, async-await

I am using SignalR. When conversation is done I am trying to add all recipients in conversations and notiy the online ones.

All code is good but **it notifies only the first recipient.** so I suppose broadcasting is waiting only for the first time

```
public void NotifyConversation(ConversationModel model, string name)
{
    var groupId = model.ID.ToString();
    var recipients = model.Recipients;
    var allconnections = new List<string>();


    foreach (var recipient in recipients)
    {
        var connections = _manager.GetConnections(recipient.Name).Where(x => x != null);
        allconnections.AddRange(connections);
    }

    var tasks = allconnections
        .Select(connection =>
                Task.Run(() => { Context.Groups.Add(connection, groupId); })).ToArray();

    Task.WaitAll(tasks);

    Context.Clients.Group(groupId).broadcastConversation(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Groups.Add is asynchronous.  You're creating a task to run the Groups.Add but it completes almost instantly because the inner part of the task does not wait until the groups.add has completed.

Therefore you need to wait until the groups.Add has completed inside your Task.Run.

Something like:

```
var tasks = allconnections
    .Select(connection =>
            Task.Run(() => { Context.Groups.Add(connection, groupId).Wait(); })).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

`Add()` is asynchronous: it returns a `Task`. `Task.Run()` understands this, but you need to return that `Task` to it (notice that the lambda is no longer in a block):

```
Task.Run(() => Context.Groups.Add(connection, groupId))
```

This is similar to calling `Wait()` on the returned `Task`, except that it's better, because it doesn't block a thread.